# Difference of field definitions inside python class

Tags: python, class, type-hinting, pydantic

In pydantic, you often see models like the following:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    f1: int
    f2: float
    f3: str

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')
```

now I understand that the `:` fields are meant to contain the real model data and the `=` field is instead a class behavior configuration item, but what's the technical difference between the two styles of declaration? As far as I know, for field inside classes you can only use the `=` assignment, to instantiate fields which you can later refer to with `self.blah`. What's with the colon declaration? Are those type hints?

Comment: Yes, those are type hints. Not sure about pydantic, but in standard Python those just provide typing hints, and do not actually define the attributes - trying to access them in code will result in an error.

Comment: Yes, those are type hints. Pydantic uses those for type validation purposes. You can also configure your editor/linter/whatever to use them to generate errors if you attempt to assign a value of the wrong type to the variable (which is to say, they're useful even if you're not using pydantic).

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are *variable annotations*, for which any use other than type hints is deprecated but not forbidden. `BaseModel` uses a metaclass that does more with the annotations than `type` would for a "regular" class.